# exactly even divisible using python recurssion

Tags: python, recursion, recursive-query

```py
def extractlyEvenlyDivisibleHelp(inputlst, number, outputlst = []):
    if number == 0:
        print([])
        return
    if inputlst[0] % number == 0:
        outputlst.append(inputlst[0])
        outputlst.sort()


    inputlst.remove(inputlst[0])

    if len(inputlst) == 0:
        print(outputlst)
    else:
        extractlyEvenlyDivisibleHelp(inputlst, number, outputlst)


def extractlyEvenlyDivisible(input, number):
    extractlyEvenlyDivisibleHelp(input, number, [])


extractlyEvenlyDivisible([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], 0)                                                
extractlyEvenlyDivisible([1,2,-3,4,5,-6,7,8,9,9,6], -3)
extractlyEvenlyDivisible([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10, 10], 5)
```

Output:

```
[ ]

[-6, -3, 6, 9, 9]

[5, 10, 10]
```

Expected output:

```
[ ]

[-6, -3, 6, 9]

[5, 10]
```

I need help, as I need only one 9, I mean if I input couple times the same digit, it should return only one time.

Comment: Try adding the numbers to a [set](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) instead of a list? Convert to list later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could filter out duplicates from the input list before passing to the helper using [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-set):

```
def extractlyEvenlyDivisible(inputlst, number):
    extractlyEvenlyDivisibleHelp(list(set(inputlst)), number, [])
```

Also it is bad practice to redefine built-ins like `input` even in a function, I would change this to a different variable name